# Get all <a> tags which do not contain a rel="nofollow"

Tags: regex, perl, ack

I've written a small command to find all files which contain external url's, using `ack` and open them in sublime, so I can do a find and replace on all tags and add a `rel="nofollow"`:

```
sublime $(ack -l '<a[^>]+href="http')
```

But now I would like to make sure those `<a>` tags do not already contain a `rel="nofollow"`. Anyone who can help me out?

I just need to get all `<a>` tags which contain a `href="http` (so I'm pretty sure it's an external url), but probably it's better if I could check it contained a `href="<do not contain website.nl>"`, so a href without `website.nl`. And it may not contain a `rel="nofollow"`.

Would be a great bonus if it could check on `rel="nofollow"` and `rel='nofollow'` (so single and double quotes, same for `href`) But I could run the same command a couple of times, with and without double quotes, so it wouldn't be that much of an issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe ack uses Perl regex patterns, in which case you should use a negative look-ahead, like this

```
$ sublime $(ack -l '<a\b(?=[^>]+\bhref="http)(?![^>]+\brel="nofollow")')
```

But note that ack will check only one line at a time whereas an HTML `<a>` element may run over several lines

Comment: Very nice! Thanks! Works like a charm!! :) And indeed, according to their website ack does use Perl regex patterns: http://beyondgrep.com/why-ack/.